# Easy way to search array of dictionary

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have a NSArray looking like:

```
 [{@"firstName":@"abc", @"lastName":@"ABC"},
   ...
  {@"firstName":@"xyz", @"lastName":@"XYZ"}]
```

I want to get the dictionary element in which lastName=XYZ, that is, the array element:

```
  {@"firstName":@"xyz", @"lastName":@"XYZ"}
```

is there an easy way to get it without a lot of loops?  Thanks.

Comment: Yup, use `- [NSSet objectsPassingTest:]`.

Comment: @H2CO3 That method is on `NSSet`, not `NSArray`.

Comment: @Gavin Oops, sorry, it is. (It should be easy to make a set out of an array, so I edited my comment.)

Answer (score 1):

```
NSArray *people = ...;
NSUInteger chosenIndex = [people indexOfObjectPassingTest:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSDictionary *person = obj;
    return [person[@"lastName"] isEqualToString:@"XYZ"];
}];
if (chosenIndex != NSNotFound) {
    NSDictionary *chosenPerson = people[chosenIndex];
    NSLog(@"I chose %@", chosenPerson);
}
```